# Confusion about calculating integral with $d(-x)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, definite-integrals, change-of-variable

I'm wondering if $\int_{a}^{b}g(z)d(-z)=-\int_{a}^{b}g(z)dz$. On the one hand, intuitively this seems true as this looks like we are putting a negative sign on the $\Delta z$ in the Rieman sum, so it should act like we could taking the constant -1 outside the integral. On the other hand, using rigorous change of variable, let $t=-z$ and we will get $\int_{a}^{b}g(z)d(-z)=\int_{a}^{b}g(-t)dt$.

My question is: how to interpret $\int_{a}^{b} g(z)d(-z)$ (or what does $d$ of something represent), and intuitively why you cannot simply take the minus sign out? Thanks!

Comment: This would be an example of a Riemann-Stieljies integral, something of the set up $\int f(x) dg(x)$

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thanks. I just checked, and found $\int f(x)dg(x)=\int f(x)g'(x)dx$, so this means $\int_{a}^{b}g(z)d(-z)=-\int_{a}^{b}g(z)dz$ should be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the domain of the integral as well : $$\int_a^bg(z)d(-z)=\int g(z)\chi_{[a,b]}(z)d(-z)=\int g(-t)\chi_{[-b,-a]}(t)dt=\int_{-b}^{-a}g(-t)dt$$$$=-\int_a^bg(t)dt.$$

Comment: Thanks. I thought I don't need to change the domain as [a,b] is the range for $-z$, which is the same as $t$. Is this interpretation wrong? Or in general, when we write $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)d(g(x))$, is the $[a,b]$ here the range for $g(x)$ or $x$?  It would be great if you could give me some textbook reference.

Comment: Seems like $[a,b]$ is the range for $x$.

Comment: @TD888 Yes, that interpretation is wrong. If $g$ is only defined on $[a,b]$, then what do you even mean by $g(-a)$ or $g(-b)$? And for the second question, it does not make sense by writing $d(g(x))$. First of all to write such an expression, $g(x)$ must be monotone continuous function on the given interval that you are interested in. For the reference, which level are you studying in? I guess you did not study Lebesgue integral, right?

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful! I studied calculus very long time ago, haven't systematically studied real analysis including Lebesgue integral.

Comment: @TD888 Then I really recommend you to learn measure theory and Lebesgue integration. This may take some time and effort if you are studying on your own, but definitely will clear up your mind about integration. Real Analysis: Measure Theory, Integration, and Hilbert Spaces (Princeton Lectures in Analysis) by Elias M.Stein is easy book explaining the concept very well. If you don't have a time to study, then I recommend you to not use notations like $d(g(x))$.

Comment: Thanks! Btw, just curious, does the notation $d(g(x))$ exist? If yes, how does its meaning differ from $dg(x)$?

Comment: @TD888 Kinda yes, but I think what you meant by $d(g(x))$ is different from the general notation of measure : for example, $\int f(x) d\mu(x)$,$\int fd\mu$, $\int f(x)\mu(dx)$ notations are often used. (all three are same meaning, meaning that Lebesgue integration of $f$ with given measure $\mu$, with respect to the variable $x$.)